# Python - print statistics from one file into another

Tags: python

```
import sys
import pickle
import string

def Menu():
    print ("***********MENU************")
    print ("0. Quit")
    print ("1. Read text file")
    print ("2. Display counts")
    print ("3. Display statistics of word lengths")
    print ("4. Print statistics to file")

def readFile():
    while True:
            fileName = input("Please enter a file name: ")
        if (fileName.lower().endswith(".txt")):
                break
        else:
                print("That was an incorrect file name. Please try again.")
        continue
    return fileName


THE_FILE = ""
myDictionary = 0

def showCounts(fileName):    
    numCount = 0
    dotCount = 0
    commaCount = 0
    lineCount = 0
    wordCount = 0

    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                wordCount+=len(line.split())
                lineCount+=1
                for char in line:
                        if char.isdigit() == True:
                            numCount+=1
                        elif char == '.':
                            dotCount+=1
                        elif char == ',':
                            commaCount+=1

    print("Number count: " + str(numCount))
    print("Comma count: " + str(commaCount))
    print("Dot  count: " + str(dotCount))
    print("Line count: " + str(lineCount))
    print("Word count: " + str(wordCount))

def showStats(fileName):
    temp1 = []
    temp2 = []
    lengths = []
    myWords = []
    keys = []
    values = []
    count = 0

    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                temp2.append(word)
                temp1.append(len(word))

        for x in temp1:
            if x not in lengths:
                lengths.append(x)

        lengths.sort()

    dictionaryStats = {}
    for x in lengths:
        dictionaryStats[x] = []

    for x in lengths:
        for word in temp2:
            if len(word) == x:
                dictionaryStats[x].append(word)

    for key in dictionaryStats:
        print("Key = " + str(key) + " Total number of words with " + str(key) + " characters = " + str(len(dictionaryStats[key])))        
    return dictionaryStats

def printStats(aDictionary):
    aFile = open("statsWords.dat", 'w')
    for key in aDictionary:
        aFile.write(str(key) + " : " +  str(aDictionary[key]) + "\n")        
    aFile.close()

choice = -1

while choice !=0:
    Menu()
    choice = (int(input("Please choose 1-4 to perform function. Press 0 to exit the program. Thank you. \n")))
    if choice == 0:
        print ("Exit program. Thank you.")
        sys.exit
    elif choice == 1:
            THE_FILE = readFile()
    elif choice == 2:
            showCounts(THE_FILE)
    elif choice == 3:
            showStats(THE_FILE)
    elif choice == 4:
            printStats(myDictionary)        
    else: 
        print ("Error.")
```

I'm trying to open a file, have it display the statistics of the word lengths, and then have it make a new file with the statistics of the word lengths. I can read the file and have it display the statistics, but when I print the statistics to file I get an error - "int" object is not iterable. Any ideas? Thanks guys!

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw4_ThomasConnor.py", line 111, in <module>
    printStats(myDictionary)        
  File "hw4_ThomasConnor.py", line 92, in printStats
    for key in aDictionary:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: please include the actual error/traceback, it should include the line number where the error is

Comment: What about providing complete stack trace - it will probably point to exact line in your code and will tell, that you are going to iterate over integer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set `myDictionary` to `0` at the top of your program, and then are sending it to your file writing function here `printStats(myDictionary)`.

In this function you have this line `for key in aDictionary`, and since you passed in `0`, this is effectively `for key in  0` which is where the error comes from.

You need to send the result of the `showStats` function to your `printStats` function.

As this is looking like homework, I will leave it at that for now.

---

> Sorry I am confused. in the showStats function I have to somehow say
>   "send results to printStats function" and then in the printStats
>   function I have to call the results? How would I do that exactly?

The printStats function is expecting a dictionary to print. This dictionary is generated by the showStats function (in fact, it returns this dictionary).

So you need to send the result of the showStats function to the printStats function.

To save the return value of a method, you can assign it on the LHS (left hand side) of the call expression, like this:

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...    return bar*2
...
>>> def print_results(result):
...    print('The result was: {}'.format(result))
...
>>> result = foo(2)  # Save the returned value
```

Since `result` is just like any other name in Python,  you can pass it to any other function:

```
>>> print_results(result)
The result was: 4
```

If we don't want to store the result of the function, and just want to send it to another function, then we can use this syntax:

```
>>> print_results(foo(2))
The result was: 4
```

You need to do something similar in your main loop where you execute the functions.

Since the dictionary you want to print is returned by the showStats function, you must call the showStats function first before calling the printStats function.  This poses a problem if your user selects 4 before selecting 3 - make sure you find out a work around for this. A simple work around would be to prompt the user to calculate the stats by selecting 3 before selecting 4.  Try to think of another way to get around this problem.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. in the showStats function I have to somehow say "send results to printStats function" and then in the printStats function I have to call the results? How would I do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
THE_FILE = ""
myDictionary = 0
```

you set integer to `myDictionary`.

and later you do:

```
printStats(myDictionary)
```

and as you try to interate over keys of dictionary inside, you fail.